# command fails from exec() but works on terminal

Tags: java, linux, runtime.exec, pdftotext

I'm trying to convert pdf to txt by using Java. I've tried Apache PDFBox but, for some weird reason, it doesn't convert the whole document. For this reason I decided to use pdftotext by executing a Runtime.getRuntime().exec() call. The problem is that, while on my terminal pdftotext works flawlessly, the exec() call gives me error code 1 (sometimes even 99).
Here's the call:

```
pdftotext "/home/www-data/CANEFS_TEST/Hello/ciao.pdf" "/tmp/ciao.pdf.txt"
```

Here's the code

```
private static File callPDF2Text(File input,File output){
    assert input.exists();
    assert Utils.getExtension(input).equalsIgnoreCase("pdf");
    assert Utils.getExtension(output).equalsIgnoreCase("txt") : output.getAbsoluteFile().toString();

    Process p=null;

    try {
        System.out.println(String.format(
                PDF2TXT_COMMAND,
                input.getAbsolutePath(),
                output.getAbsolutePath()));
        p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String.format(
                PDF2TXT_COMMAND,
                input.getAbsolutePath(),
                output.getAbsolutePath()));
        p.waitFor();
        if (p.exitValue()!=0){
            throw new RuntimeException("exit value for pdftotext is "+p.exitValue());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    return output;
}
```

Here's PDF2TXT_COMMAND string definition:

```
public static final String PDFTXT_COMMAND="pdftotext \"%s\" \"%s\"";
```

I know that usually these kinds of errors are caused by the permission setup. So, here 's the output of ls -l command on the Hello folder:

```
ls -l /home/www-data/CANEFS_TEST/Hello/
total 136
-rwxrwxr-- 1 www-data www-data 136041 mar 27 16:31 ciao.pdf
```

Also, note that the user creating the process is koldar, which is in the group www-data itself.
Thank you for your time and patience!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use " in your format string... These chars are specially parsed by the shell and you don't use a shell to launch the command...

I can suggest you to use `exec(String [])` not `exec(String)` so that you will be able to *separate* each arg of your command:

```
String []command = new String[3];
command[0] = "pdftotext";
command[1] = input.getAbsolutePath();
command[2] = output.getAbsolutePath();
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

That should work. If it doesn't, that may be a question of access rights on dir.

Comment: ok, this works, but what happens if the pdf filename has a whitespace within it? Never mind... it works too! thank you very much!

Comment: This is guaranteed to work! Each args will be passed to the system as is! Your are forced to use " with the shell because you want to say: this is a single arg. Using `exec(String [])` bypass any parsing.

Comment: that was indeed a really stupid question. Thanks again!